# How can i play Youtube Videos on Android TV

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, android-tv

I want to play youtube videos in my android TV application, have tried youtube player api, but it wont work in TVs not having youtube app. I tried using webview, it is not playing the video(I am using Android TV API Level 25).

I am open to use any video player.

Please can anyone suggest me a good way of streaming youtube videos on Android TV?

Comment: Can try this library: https://github.com/bertrandmartel/youtubetv

Comment: Thank you! webview is not working with all the TV. Thanks a lot for responding.

Answer (score 0):

try this [library](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player) it's working fine[image]